# How can connect jupyter notebook in desired environment in Anaconda in server computer by using Putty?

Tags: server, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, putty, ssh-tunnel

I'm trying to connect to server computer from my desktop computer via Putty to use capacity and source of powerful server remotely via Tunneling and applying localhost address and port. The problem is I have successfully installed Anaconda in server and created environment([CR7]) and installed Keras and tensorflow and already tested them via python but when I call jupyter notebook and import tensorflow in my environment [CR7], I face `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'` which is ridiculous as following [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4WesZ.jpg):

[image: img]

Why it's the case and how can I fix that?

Should I install TF nad Keras in root environment in Anaconda?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Update** I've just installed TF & Keras in root in server and it works but still I can't access my already built environment via Jupyter notebook and run TF & Keras!!! I don;t want to work in root environments due to some consequences!

BTW **Python version** is 3.7.1

Comment: do you have multiple python versions installed?

Comment: @Vishal I checked python version is 3.7.1 it's not multiple python!

Comment: how you have added 6666 as source port?

Comment: you should append "--port=<>" with the `jupyter notebook` command.

Comment: @Vishal 6666 is faked one I use another port, don't take it serious.would you leave your mentioned command?

Comment: @Vishal by help of HLF in answer I tried a command but didn't work and see [CR7] in kernel lists!  check [here](https://i.imgur.com/AtYcOI1.jpg)

Comment: do you have mobaxterm in your local computer? In my work, everyday I use to login from my local computer to run jupyter on remote server. I use mobaxterm, but I had tried with putty also and it is very easy. One thing is that, I had created a script and then I run that script with python.

Comment: @Vishal I don't have mobaxterm and I just can use putty. may I ask you what's that script?

Answer (score 2):

I could find a solution based on [Anaconda documentation](http://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/user-guide/tasks/use-jupyter-notebook-extensions/) **Using Jupyter Notebook extensions**. Basically I should have installed **Notebook Conda Kernels (nb_conda_kernels)** in my desired environment via:

```
conda install nb_conda_kernels
```

After installing, there would be the option in Jupyter Notebook to **Change kernel** from the 'Kernel' menu in the Jupyter Notebook.
[image: img]

Answer (score 1):

In the screenshot you use Python 3 env. Go to Kernel/Change kernel > select CR7 environment.

Comment: I wish I had this option where you addressed me, check out this [pic](https://i.imgur.com/u8oOxuS.jpg)

Comment: you can try this in command line: python -m ipykernel install --user --name CR7 --display-name "Python (CR7)"

Comment: I tried but still I can't change the kernel to my desired environment which is [CR7] and it still shows and run TF & Keras from root environment , look [here](https://i.imgur.com/AtYcOI1.jpg)